# Limiting number of nested resources in Django Tastypie?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to work out the following [example](http://obroll.com/django-tastypie-one-to-many-fields-related-models-reverse-backward/). I just want to ask, how to you limit the number of results in the nested resources? How would I just get only the first 10 policies in the given example.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm,

Instead of passing the attribute, you can pass a method that returns the queryset:

**SchoolResource**:

```
class SchoolResource(ModelResource):
    # fields.ToManyField('APP.api.RelatedResource', 'related name')
    policies = fields.ToManyField('places.api.PolicyResource', 
        attribute=lambda bundle: Policy.objects.filter(school=bundle.obj)[:10]
    )

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'school'
        queryset = School.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
```

See this:
http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tomanyfield

I hope I was helpful =]